# Accessing a printer and shared folder from a different network

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router, printer

I am connected to a router that's plugged directly online.
The other router is heavily firewalled, but allows access to a windows shared folder and a printer.

Both networks have ethernet and wifi access.

What would be the easiest way to connect to the internet via the first network, yet access the printer and shared folder from the second?

It's a Win7 machine.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to set a specific route, in your routing table, for the IP addresses corresponding to the printer and to the network share, that goes through the correct ("other") router, while leaving in the meantime the default gateway set as the first router.

Answer (score 0):

You could connect them via a VPN using Hamachi and then directly share between the two.

https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/